# Ubuntu not recognizing memory card as a drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, memory-card

I need to create a partition on a memory card (CompactFlash).
I bought a [USB memory card reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00R07WNRY), and inserted a 512MB CF.
There are console messages (see below) indicating that the card was recognized as /dev/sda, but it didn't mount and neither "fdisk -l" nor gparted show the device. Do I have to take some special action first? I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.

Here are the messages I saw after removing and re-inserting the CF memory card into the reader. The last line is repeated a lot:

```
[  403.765912] usb 1-2.4: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  403.891635] usb 1-2.4: New USB device found, idVendor=3207, idProduct=0300, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  403.891651] usb 1-2.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  403.891659] usb 1-2.4: Product: 816820090226
[  403.891664] usb 1-2.4: Manufacturer: 816820090226
[  403.891669] usb 1-2.4: SerialNumber: 816820090226
[  403.897043] usb-storage 1-2.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  403.897687] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-2.4:1.0
[  406.940691] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     FNK TECH USB CARD READER  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  406.941066] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  406.943678] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[  406.944206] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  510.687666] usb 1-2.4: reset high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  541.874180] usb 1-2.4: reset high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
```

I also saw these lines initially upon bootup:

```
[   79.946718] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   79.946730] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[   79.946742] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[   79.946748] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0-byte physical blocks
[   79.946759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   79.946765] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[   79.946775] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[   79.946822] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   79.947617] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Update: I had another bad drive plugged in which seems to have been generating the disk errors. I unplugged it and re-plugged my memory card reader and no longer see the errors or reset messages, but I still can't access the drive. I only see:

```
[ 4982.445660] usb 1-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 4991.829552] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 4991.978100] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=3207, idProduct=0300, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 4991.978117] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4991.978124] usb 1-1: Product: 816820090226
[ 4991.978130] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: 816820090226
[ 4991.978135] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 816820090226
[ 4991.981478] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4991.982072] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4994.984977] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     FNK TECH USB CARD READER  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 4994.985840] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[ 4994.988048] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 4994.989148] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 5250.562148]  nvme1n1: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6
```

Comment: "Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK" means that it cannot read the CF card.  Either a defective adapter or the card itself is going/is bad.

Comment: @Terrance Does the fact that I only see this initially, and don't see it again when removing/re-inserting the CF card, imply that the issue is the adapter, rather than the card itself?

Comment: @Terrance Actually I think that error was from another external drive I had plugged in that I've had trouble reading. I unplugged it. Then I unplugged my memory-card reader and replugged it (this time directly rather than through a hub), and don't see any error. But I still can't access the card.

Comment: I have an 8-in-1 USB reader that gives me `usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected`, `scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9454 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0` and so on without any errors. It shows that it tried to mount a drive as `Media removed` message.  If you insert the reader without the CF card it in and see something similar with running `sudo dmesg` each time, then probably a bad CF card.  If you're not seeing anything like that, probably a bad adapter.

Comment: Some media cards have a tiny slide switch on the side that makes them read only. Does yours have that "feature"?

Comment: It turns out that the adapter was bad. I bought another identical one which works fine. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Terrance the issue was a bad adapter. I bought another identical one which works fine.